# Ticks vanish in pgfplots if groupplot is combined with set layers and axis on top

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots, pgflayers

I am trying to use `set layers` to get the grid behind the tick labels and `axis on top=true` to get the axis on top of the plot lines.
If I use these settings in a `groupplot` neither the `ticks` nor their labels are visible. The extra grid lines are missing as well.

Can someone tell me if this is a bug or working as intended and how to get what I want.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbch]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}
        [   group style={
                  group name=my plots,
                  group size=1 by 1},
            set layers,
            axis on top=true,
        ]
            \nextgroupplot[
                    extra x ticks       = {-1,0,1},
                    extra x tick labels = {},
                    extra x tick style  = { grid = major, 
                                            major grid style 
                                                 = {thick, black!25!white, 
                                                   dashed}}
            ]
                \addplot{ x^2 };
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `set layers` to get what you want. Just `axis on top` is sufficient and `axis on top` itself sets layers.

[image]

I have made the grid black just for illustration.

If you insist on using `set layers` put it after `\begin{tikzpicture}` like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
```

But for this particular case, it is not doing much. You have to define a new layer for achieving your goal and then use it.

Always remember that `set layers` can't be used inside local groups such as `groupplot`. See the limitation on page 354 of `pgfplots` manual.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbh]   %% no c option valid
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\pgfplotsset{set layers}   %% <---- put here
        \begin{groupplot}
        [   group style={
                  group name=my plots,
                  group size=1 by 1},
            axis on top=true,
        ]
            \nextgroupplot[
                    extra x ticks       = {-1,0,1},
                    extra x tick labels = {},
                    extra x tick style  = { grid = major,
                                            major grid style
                                                 = {thick, black,
                                                   dashed}},
             ]
                \addplot{ x^2 };
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `axis on top` sets layers.

Comment: You still have set layers inside your example. Did you mean to remove it? Because as it is your example doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MrZ Yes sorry, it escaped my eyes. You have to remove it. Now it is corrected.

Comment: Ok, I copied your example and the markers are in front of the grid. But the plot line isn't. Any ideas? (TeX-Live, pdflatex)

Comment: @MrZ It won't as `axis on top` is used. The sequence of plotting is `axis background,main,axis grid,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,%
axis descriptions,axis foreground`. The `main` is where the plot comes. Ultimately, as it seems, you won't even need `axis on top`, remove it and you will get the sequence: plot then grid and then the ticks.

Comment: @MrZ What you need is `standard` layer set which is loaded by default.

Comment: With the default, the `ticks` and `axis lines` are behind the plot line and plot markers

Comment: I think I will start a new question, as this does not seem to be related to the main question of using `set layers` in combination with `groupplot`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23695/discussion-between-mr-z-and-harish-kumar).